# Completeness axiom supremum

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove the existence of $\inf$ using the existence of $\sup$ using suitable conditions? I can prove it individually, but proving using $\sup$ is confusing.

Comment: To prove A has the greatest lower bound , consider L = set of all lower bounds of A. Then show sup L = inf A.

Answer (score 1):

For dealing with supremum of a sequence of real numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3\dots$ you many consider the sequence $-a_1,-a_2,-a_3\dots$ and deal with its infimum, this should serve fine, you can find the supremem of the original sequence by finding the infimum of the last sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a set of real numbers, denote by
$$
-A=\{-x:x\in A\}
$$
(the set of negatives of elements in $A$).

Then prove that $A$ is lower bounded if and only if $-A$ is upper bounded and that, in this case,
$$
\inf A=-\sup(-A)
$$

This “duality” allows to almost halve the proofs of facts about the sup and the inf: the proof of every statement is equivalent to the proof of the “dual statement”, where you exchange “sup” with “inf” and $\le$ with $\ge$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be an ordered set such that every non-empty subset of $X$ that is bounded above has a least upper bound.

Now let $A$ be a non-empty subset of $X$ that is bounded below.

That means exactly that the set $L:=\{x\in X\mid x\text{ is a lower bound of }A\}$ is not empty.

We have $a\in A$ for some $a\in A$ and evidently $a$ is an upper bound of $L$.

So the non-empty $L\subset X$ is bounded above and we conclude that it has a least upper bound.

Denote it by $s$.

Every element of $A$ is an upper bound of $L$ so $s\leq a$ for every $a\in A$.

This tells us that $s\in L$.

Also $x>s$ implies that $x\notin L$ so $s$ serves as largest lower bound of $A$.